# Shift and masking in C

Tags: c, bit-shift, bitmask, variable-length

I have this problem. I have a payload that dinamically change its length. If I don't cut this payload, I will have also informations that are rubbish for me. So I want to cut the payload in base of my payload length.

I have this part of code:

```
uint64_t data_tmp = HTONLL((uint64_t) zp->data);
uint8_t len = zp->length;
uint64_t mask = 0xFFFF >> (64 - len);
data_tmp = data_tmp & mask;
printf("DATA_TMP = %llu\n", data_tmp);
```

zp->data is after written into a t->payload field. So this is my payload. It's a 64 bit field.

I want to temporary take this payload.
Calculate my payload length, that is the zp->length field, of type uint8.
After I would create a mask that shift of 64 byte - payload_length in the way that I can then apply it to the temporary payload and obtain a field with only data I want and all zeros.

How can I do this?

For example. If payload_length is 01 and payload 00+..............(rubbish)
I want obtain a payload like 00000000 on 64 byte.

If my payload_length is 13 and payload 1284732089322309....
I want obtain only thirtheen bytes.

Sorry if it's difficult to say...

Comment: i think you need binary and, not logic and. try `data_tmp=data_tmp&mask`

Comment: how is `zp->data` declared?

Comment: Is your payload 64 bits wide or 64 bytes?

Comment: @Kyborek, Should be an answer not a comment :)

Comment: zp->data is uint64. 64bit sorry I made a mistake

Comment: Another question. Why do you need `htonl`? Is your data in network byte order? Thing is, `htonl` works with uint32_t.

Comment: Yeah right! First error. But I didn't still resolve my problem

Comment: I edited the question. The mask is correctly written?

Comment: @sharkbait, sorry, no. If `len` is 3, `0xFFFF >> (64 - len)` will rotate `0xFFFF` to the right 61 times, which means, you will get 0. If `len` is 60 (for example), the mask will be `0xFFF` (rotated 4 bits right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
uint64_t mask = (1uLL << (len * 4)) - 1;
data_tmp = data_tmp & mask;
```

This will give you the *lowest* `len` of 4-bit digits. If you need highest instead, you can rotate `data_tmp` before applying the mask:

```
data_tmp >>= (64 - len * 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood your question correctly, but you use logical AND instead of binary AND.

expression "variable && variable" evaluates to 1 or 0

expression "variable & variable" evaluates to binary AND which, with your proper mask, will crop the data as you propably intended